# How to slicing image and stretchable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, slice

I need to stretch image right and left side centre half circle remain as it is. also need half circle in center

[image]

I have tried slicing concept and also tried below code

```
UIImage *image = self.imgBGBottom.image;
CGFloat capWidth =  floorf(image.size.width / 2) - 50;
CGFloat capHeight =  0;
UIImage *capImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:
                     UIEdgeInsetsMake(capHeight, capWidth, capHeight, capWidth)];

[self.imgBGBottom setImage:capImage];
```

but it is not working for me

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slicing works well in Xcode. What did you do and what did not work? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

Comment: @brainray i need to stretch both side, half circle remain as it is.

Comment: @Monish Please check my answer, you are using incorrect method to stretch image but it works with some images only.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara : I have tried your ans but it will stretch form only left side.

Comment: @Monish I have updated my answer, check updated answer.

Comment: @Monish have you tried?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara : it will stretch only one side 
i need to stretch both side for half circle center

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122475/discussion-between-dipen-panchasara-and-monish).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using function, use `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight` instead `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets`.

Set top, left cap to stretch your image as described in following code.

**Objective-C**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];

CGFloat capTop =  50;  // top cap to keep half round as is
CGFloat capLeft = 5; // To repeat it or stretch equally.
UIImage *capImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:capLeft topCapHeight:capTop];
```

**Swift**

```
let image =  UIImage(named: "stretchableImage")

let capTop:Int =  50;  // top cap to keep half round as is
let capLeft:Int = 5; // To repeat it or stretch equally.
let capImage = image?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: capLeft, topCapHeight: capTop)
```

### Alternet Solution

Same result can be achieved using following function as well.

**Objective-C**

```
UIImage *stretchedImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:
                 UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 0, 50)];
```

**Swift**

```
var stretchedImage = image?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 50), resizingMode: .stretch)
```

> **Note :** Keep stretchable image as small as possible otherwise it will not stretch properly with smaller image container(ImageView, Button etc.). You can reduce height & width of your existing image.

Comment: It's not stretching left and right side, it's stretching center. There is not so big stretching, so it's hard to recognize how half-circle becomes half-oval

Comment: @Cy-4AH Coordinates to stretch images like top & left vary based upon the image you are trying to stretch. I am not sure which image are you trying to stretch. It would be good if you could provide an image or post question for the same & share a link.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
UIImage *image = self.imgBGBottom.image;
CGFloat capWidth =  floorf(image.size.width / 2) - 50;
CGFloat capTop =  50;  //the value is determined by the half circle height,i guess it is 50 height
CGFloat capBottom = 0;
UIImage *capImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:
                             UIEdgeInsetsMake(capHeight, capTop, capBottom, capWidth)];

[self.imgBGBottom setImage:capImage];
```

Comment: it is not working. It has repeated half circle in image